# C++ Reference of vector

Tags: c++, reference, vector

class Refvect
    {
    public:
        vector &refv;
        Refvect(int t, vector &refv = vector()) : refv(refv) { };
        void operator()()
        {
            refv.clear();
        }
    };
    int main () 
    {
        Refvect r(0);
        r();
    }

With Visual Studio 2010, this gives me an error : "vector iterators incompatible" at the execution, but I don't understand why (but I can insert elements in refv without any problem).
The temporary object vector() lives as long as the reference, no?

Comment: Note that the ability to bind a temporary to a non-const reference is a VS extension, the standard only allows binding temporaries to const references.

Comment: @avakar - that has only been available "on request" for backward compatibility for about 12 years. The default is to conform with the standard.

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker, I don't know what you mean by "on request". I've just created a new empty project in vs10 and I was able to bind a temporary to a non-const reference without requesting anything. Visual Studio actually behaves the other way around -- you have to request standard behavior if you want it (/Za).

Comment: I can't believe it... how is it *still* like that? I'd got the impression back at VS 6 that it had been fixed (I thought they'd had to fix a lot of their own library code and were proud about it at the time).

Answer (score 4):

As soon as the statement

```
Refvect r(0);
```

is executed (control passes beyond the semicolon) the temporary `vector<int> &refv = vector<int>()` is destroyed. Now the reference stored inside the class object is *dangling* - not bound to any live object. Trying to access the object  through such reference is undefined behavior.

Comment: +1. One should store the actual vector instead of a copy to that vector.

Comment: @Billy - no.  one should store a copy of the actual vector instead of a reference to the original most of the time.

Comment: @Noah Roberts: Thanks for catching my typo. Please replace "copy" with "reference"

Comment: If it did that, @Billy, it wouldn't be much of a `Refvect` anymore. Storing a reference appears to be the entire purpose of the class. The only change necessary seems to be to remove the possibility of a default argument. In other words, when you want a vector reference, you need to provide your own vector; the reference class can't provide one of its own — at least not through a default parameter.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: I assumed that the class was an example; not real code. If it's purpose is to store the reference then the OP should store the reference, not a class whose sole purpose is to contain that reference.

Answer (score 1):

> The temporary object vector() lives as
>   long as the reference, no?

No!

Temporaries destruct at the end of the outermost enclosing expression - i.e. an expression that is embedded in a statement rather than another expression. There is no magic tracking of references to ensure that objects live as long as references to them - that would be garbage collection.

**Update:**

In response to your comment:

> if I use `const vector<int> &refv;` it
>   works

I'm not sure how that could be. If you add `const` to the parameter `refv` then it is no longer compatible with the member and so should not compile. If you change the member to `const` also then you should find that you cannot call `clear` on it, because it that is not a `const` member function.

And if you've found something in C++ that "seems to work", then you're using C++ in completely the wrong way!

There a lots of ways for something to "seem to work" in C++ under highly specific special circumstances, but which will fail more obviously if those circumstances are altered. This is called "undefined behaviour" - the results may include *apparent* correct behaviour, sometimes.

The most common form is where data ceases to be valid even when there is still a means of accessing it, which is the situation you have here.

The correct way to use C++ is to thoroughly understand the limits of defined behaviour and stay well inside them, as far as you possibly can. In particular you need to understand how long objects live for, so you can ensure that references to objects don't live longer than the objects they refer to.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but now if I use const vector<int> &refv; it works?